# How to restore USB drive after using Startup Disk Creator on Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb

I recently used Startup Disk Creator on Ubuntu 17.04 to create a bootable Ubuntu 17.10 on a 16 GB USB drive. The USB does boot and live disk works. 
But when I plug in the USB to use it on Windows 10 or my installed Ubuntu 17.04, it shows the size of USB to be only 2.22 MB out of which 18 KB is free.
How to restore the USB drive to the previous state of 16 GB storage?

Comment: You can try to resize the partition you made and make a second partition or reformat the usb to FAT or NTFS

Comment: Can you please refer me to some article or guide as to how to do that? @Panther

Comment: gparted will do this - https://www.howtoforge.com/partitioning_with_gparted . As you are not running Ubuntu from the flash drive you can do this from Ubuntu `sudo apt install gparted`

Comment: An easier to use option is installing MKUSB and using its "Restore to a standard storage device" function.